# Click event outside the shadow DOM in web-component returns the "Document" as the event.target

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension, web-component

I have a chrome extension, written in pure JS, that its content script detects and listens for every click event on a web pages.

A click event fires when a user clicks on a nested shadow dom inside a web component,
However, the target is the entire document.
Based on some articles about web components and shadow doms, It appears I can identify clicks via event.composedPath() if shadow dom mode is open.

Shadow DOM mode is open in my case, but the event.path points to the document itself and not the "real" click target.

Also, I tried to add an event listener to the shadow dom element, but the event wan not fired.

Please find attached a screenshot of the web-page (I do not have access to the code, I only detect the website through my chrome extension).

[image]

I tried to write something like this ouside the web-component:

```
   document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                            console.log(event.target);  // #document
                            console.log(event.composed);  // false
                            console.log(event.composedPath()); // (2) [document, Window]
                        });
```

I tried also to add a listener to the required element itself:

```
            let elements =
                            [...document.querySelectorAll("*")].filter(
                                element => [element.tagName].some(
                                    attr => attr.startsWith("MACROPONENT")
                                )
                            );
                        console.log(elements);


            for (let element of elements) {

                            console.log(element.shadowRoot?.mode);
          
                            element.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                                console.log(event.composed);//this event is not being triggered
                            });

                            element.shadowRoot?.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                                console.log(e.target); //this event is not being triggered
                            });

                        }
```

Comment: Please add an executable StackOverflow Snippet to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: Normally it just works, no need to fiddle with shadowRoot, so apparently there's something different about this site, which is why [MCVE](/help/mcve) is necessary.